# How can I assign varaibles to json response?

Tags: python, php, perl

After running a script in python the result I get its this one.

```
[["Query 3", "2020-01-29 15:41:53", "10.1.1.5", "10.8.0.2", "SELECT p.name, XXX XXX"], ["Query 11", "2020-01-29 15:41:52", "10.1.1.5", "10.8.0.2", "SELECT CONNECTION_ID()\\G"], ["Query 12", "2020-01-29 15:41:52", "10.1.1.5", "10.8.0.2", "SELECT current_user()\\G"]]
```

How can I assign variable for each field in **Query**?

```
[["queryID", "date", "ipIntern", "ipBlabla", "queryFullfilled"], ["queryID], REPEAT....
```

There will be always 5 fields for each query, so its more easy I guess.

I want to assign variables for each field because I want to insert them on a table in database.

I just need to run another script to get all the value with variables it can be with **Php** or **Python** or **Perl**.

Answer (score 4):

You can store them in a `list` of `dictionaries` and access them by `key`, for example this will build the `list`:

```py
responses = [["Query 3", "2020-01-29 15:41:53", "10.1.1.5", "10.8.0.2", "SELECT p.name, XXX XXX"], ["Query 11", "2020-01-29 15:41:52", "10.1.1.5", "10.8.0.2", "SELECT CONNECTION_ID()\\G"], ["Query 12", "2020-01-29 15:41:52", "10.1.1.5", "10.8.0.2", "SELECT current_user()\\G"]]
fields = ["queryID", "date", "ipIntern", "ipBlabla", "queryFullfilled"]

parsed_response = [
    dict(zip(fields, response)) for response in responses
]

print(parsed_response)

>>> [{'queryID': 'Query 3', 'date': '2020-01-29 15:41:53', 'ipIntern': '10.1.1.5', 'ipBlabla': '10.8.0.2', 'queryFullfilled': 'SELECT p.name, XXX XXX'}, {'queryID': 'Query 11', 'date': '2020-01-29 15:41:52', 'ipIntern': '10.1.1.5', 'ipBlabla': '10.8.0.2', 'queryFullfilled': 'SELECT CONNECTION_ID()\\G'}, {'queryID': 'Query 12', 'date': '2020-01-29 15:41:52', 'ipIntern': '10.1.1.5', 'ipBlabla': '10.8.0.2', 'queryFullfilled': 'SELECT current_user()\\G'}]
```

This is an example if you want to access the `field` value of the `n` response:

```py
n = 1
field = "ipIntern"
print(parsed_response[n][field])


>>> 10.1.1.5
```

Comment: Is that the most viable solution? I mean I really don't want that you have done but I can work with that. My ideia was for every query the loop got (I have that on my side) when loop finish the first entry it will add to database, so I want something like the variable $queryID will output "Query 1" and it will add on database with all the other fields, then reset, and $queryID will output "Query 2"

Comment: The output I get with your code https://pastebin.com/H5FM8SG9

Comment: @HenriqueMota my `response` variable is a `list`, from the output that you are showing me in pastebin you are using it as a `str`. I gave you a fully reproducible example that outputs what I printed, test it first and then try to modify it according to your needs.

Comment: I tested your code and its working but I just change the hard core to the code I had to generate that.. the output or hardcore its the same, why it is showing like that and how can I overcome this?